# Is the direct product $\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z$ with operation $(n,m)+(p,q):=(n+p,m+q)$ a cyclic group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

Is the direct product $\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z$ with operation $(n,m)+(p,q):=(n+p,m+q)$ a cyclic group?
I know its not a cyclic group but how would i show this in a formal way?

Comment: Hint: If $(a,b)$ were the generator, then $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}=\{k(a,b):k\in\mathbb{Z}\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it were generated by one element $(a,b)$ then you'd have to have $(1,0)=n(a,b)$ which means $nb=0$.  Thus $b=0$.  Similarly $n(a,b)=(0,1)$ which implies $a=0$.  But $(0,0)$ does not generate the whole group.

Comment: Is there an element (a,b) which generates all the others?

Comment: That's what I showed, there isn't.

Comment: Ok thanks for your time

Comment: I simplified the proof, should be easy to follow now.